# vis.js crossed edges in 4.21 hierarchical graph

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

Problem: After switchnig to new (4.21) version of vis.js (from 4.18) my graph is all messed up.

EDIT: The change occurs between versions 4.19.1 and 4.20. I guess it has something to do with multiple changes in network [introduced in the 4.20 version](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/HISTORY.md).

I'm building a family free. I spent some time to get a nice looking graph. Then I found out that new version of vis.js is available. Once I decided to use it, the edges of my graph started to cross.

Here's my nice-looking graph using 4.18.1:
[image]

Here's what happens if I change to 4.21.0:
[image]

What did I do wrong? How to fix this? Same data, same code. The only difference is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.18.1/vis.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the [4.18.1 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wp0aup1c/) and [4.21.0 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLye9jap/).

And a full code with 4.21.0 reference below:

```js
    // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Person 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Person 2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Person 3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Person 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Person 5'},
  {id: 6, label: 'Person 6'},
  {id: 7, label: 'Person 7'},
  {id: 8, label: 'Person 8'},
  {id: 9, label: 'Person 9'},
  {id: 10, label: 'Person 10'},
  {id: 11, label: 'Person 11'},
  {id: 12, label: 'Person 12'},
  {id: 13, label: 'Person 13'},
  {id: 14, label: 'Person 14'},
  {id: 15, label: 'Person 15'},
  {id: 16, label: 'Person 16'},
  {id: 17, label: 'Person 17'},
  {id: 18, label: 'Person 18'},
  {id: 19, label: 'Person 19'},
  {id: 20, label: 'Person 20'},
  {id: 21, label: 'Person 21'},
  {id: 22, label: 'Person 22'},
  {id: 23, label: 'Person 23'},
  {id: 24, label: 'Person 24'},
  {id: 25, label: 'Person 25'},
  {id: 26, label: 'Person 26'},
  {id: 27, label: 'Person 27'},
  {id: 28, label: 'Person 28'},
  {id: 29, label: 'Person 29'},
  {id: 30, label: 'Person 30'},
  {id: 31, label: 'Person 31'},
    ]);
    // create an array with edges
    var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 5, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 2, to: 23, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 3, to: 2, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 4, to: 2, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 5, to: 7, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 6, to: 9, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 7, to: 13, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 8, to: 11, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 13, to: 16, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 16, to: 14, arrows:'from'},   
  {from: 18, to: 25, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 19, to: 26, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 20, to: 30, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 21, to: 28, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 22, to: 20, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 23, to: 18, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 1, to: 6, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 2, to: 22, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 3, to: 1, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 4, to: 1, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 5, to: 8, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 6, to: 10, arrows:'from'},  
  {from: 8, to: 12, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 13, to: 17, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 16, to: 15, arrows:'from'}, 
  {from: 18, to: 24, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 19, to: 27, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 20, to: 31, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 21, to: 29, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 22, to: 21, arrows:'from'},
  {from: 23, to: 19, arrows:'from'}, 
 ]);

    // create a network
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

    // provide the data in the vis format
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };

 var options = {
  layout: {
   hierarchical: {
    enabled: true,
    //levelSeparation: 130,
    nodeSpacing: 220,
    blockShifting: false,
    parentCentralization: false,
    edgeMinimization: true,
    direction: 'DU',
    sortMethod: 'directed',
   },
  },
  edges: {
   smooth: {
    type: "cubicBezier",
    forceDirection: 'vertical',
    roundness: 0.25
   },
  },
  physics: false,
 } 

    // initialize your network!
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="mynetwork"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see @floatingpurr created one just a moment ago and even my issue has been mentioned there. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Yeah, here's the issue for the reference: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/4023

Answer (score 0):

I usually save my graph with x,y position to avoid messup,
I believe you can try saving old graph with x,y potion that will help to open as is in new version.

Comment: The graph is dynamically generated upon loading the data. It's not possible to generate it with one library version and opening with newer one, if that's what you mean.