# Plotting huge trees with vis.js

Tags: javascript, charts, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm trying to plot a quite huge [network](http://visjs.org/docs/network/) (i.e., ~1k nodes and ~1k edges) with vis.js `4.21.0`. Here is my options object:

```
var options = {
    autoResize: true,
    height: '400px',
    clickToUse: false,
    layout: {
        hierarchical: {
            direction: 'UD',
            sortMethod: 'directed',
        }
    },
    physics: {
       stabilization: false,
       barnesHut: {
            gravitationalConstant: -80000,
            springConstant: 0.001,
            springLength: 200
       }
    },
    nodes: {
        shape: 'dot',
        size: 20,
        font: {
            size: 15,
            color: '#ffffff'
        },
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    groups: groups,
 };
```

The problem is that it takes up to 4 minutes to render (see this [simplified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfqbjvLt/11/)). In [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/worldCupPerformance.html), much huger than the mine, the network is rendered almost instantaneously.

How can I speed up the rendering process of my chart?

Comment: the _huger_ example uses option `physics.barnesHut` -- could this make a difference? description: _This is the fastest, default and recommended solver for non-hierarchical layouts._

Comment: I've already tried but it made no difference. PS: I added the `physics` key to the question for completeness,

Comment: The same it happens even if I do not use hierarchical layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, your fiddle doesn't have all the options you mention in your post. For instance, the network is not shown at all before several minutes passes, but if you add `physics: { stabilization: false }` it is shown at once (although it is not static at that point and slowly relaxes). Moreover, adding `barnesHut: { ... }` to `physics` and adjusting `springConstant` changes the speed of relaxation.

But here's a tricky part: compare the unrelaxed tree (with `stabilization: false`) that you have with vis.js 4.21.0 and the one that you [get](https://jsfiddle.net/pfqbjvLt/30/) with 4.19.1! It looks much nicer:

[image]

than this mess:

[image]

This was [reported earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46927541/3995261) and probably deserves more digging but what I can say for sure is 4.19.1 makes the initial tree much nicer to see stuff even before getting relaxed. With this version you can even go `physcis: false` and get this:

[image]

I'd consider using this approach although it has drawbacks:

[image]

the version with physics suffers from that to some extent too, so...

Comment: Great answer! Are there any other drawbacks when using `4.19.1`?

Comment: @floatingpurr hmm.. actually, I'm on 4.18.1 now :) Not sure if I need to update but perhaps I should check out the changelog

Comment: @floatingpurr still, this probably deserves reporting/discussing at github. It's not a nice thing to promote using an elder version of a lib and since vis.js has problems with maintainers we should help with collecting and may be even investingating issues