# Network Tree not centralized

Tags: treeview, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm tring to build a tree using Vis.js Network, like genealogy tree.
I've tried various configurations to draw graph like as tree using Vis.js Network.
I've wrote these configs:

```
{
    "interaction": {
        "zoomView": true,
        "hover": true,
        "dragNodes": true
    },
    "layout": {
        "hierarchical": {
        "direction": "UD",
        "sortMethod": "directed",
        "nodeSpacing": 150,
        "parentCentralization": false
        }
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

and:

```
{
    "interaction": {
        "zoomView": true,
        "hover": true,
        "dragNodes": true
    },
    "layout": {
        "hierarchical": {
        "direction": "UD",
        "sortMethod": "directed",
        "nodeSpacing": 150,
        "parentCentralization": true
        }
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

But my tree still growing from left to right like showing in image 
[image: Tree Growing]

My data is dynamic, when I click in a node they can expand. If needed I host to better understanding.

At first interaction the tree looks fine.

[image: First interaction]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting huge trees with vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105775/plotting-huge-trees-with-vis-js)

Comment: @YakovL isn't the same issue... I've tried it.

Comment: So you've tried to downgrade vis.js, right? Could you create a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @YakovL yes, I've tried various versions. Since 4.17, the best result was in 4.21.0

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that reproduces your issue? Otherwise it's hard to help really..

Comment: @YakovL I can make a Fiddle later... but, this is the tree https://science-tree.firebaseapp.com/#/person/la9089204821424223 when you expand some nodes(double-click), in "Karla Albuquerque de Vasconcelos Borges" and "Ivan Moura Campos"  you can see the weird growing of the tree

Comment: Please do so and also please describe in more detail what is the expected/desired behaviour and how the actual one is different

Comment: @YakovL I want a view like that https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fmffgx

Comment: @YakovL any idea?