# vis.js hierarchical network graph layout

Tags: javascript, html, vis.js, vis.js-network

I've found this strange layout in hierarchical network graph by using vis.js.
As you can see, the edges are messed up.
Any suggestion would be nice. Thanks.
Or is it possible to change the sort function by the parent node position?

#### Figure 1: The current network

[image]

#### Figure 2: The expected network

[image]

Comment: @YakovL Thank you so much for your replies on my 2 questions. And sorry for the late reply. I just saw them. The downgrade method definitely works. The network looks much better. And I will try to implement the minimap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug introduced between 4.19.1 and 4.20 according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46927541/3995261) (there's also an [issue on github](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/4023)).

An easy way is to downgrade vis.js to 4.19.1.

The hard way is to analyse the changes between the versions, contribute to the issue by reporting what you have found, forking the repo and making some rollback about those changes (and maybe making a pull request).

Answer (score 0):

In a hierarchal view,`vis-network` is ordering the nodes by there ID. for each level, the node with the lowest ID will be placed on the canvas first, and the highest will be placed last.

Answer (score 0):

```
var levelHeight = 150;
var spacing = 100;
var cordinats=network.getPositions([selectedNodes[0]])[selectedNodes[0]]
var startX = cordinats.x - (nodes.length-1)* spacing/2;
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
  var node = nodes[i];
  node.x = startX + i *spacing;
  node.y = cordinats.y + levelHeight;
}
```

i used this solution to get an good hierarchal structure