# Position of nodes in hierarchical layout to build a 'logic gate' like diagram

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm currently working on a system that allows users to create a Strategy. A Strategy can consist of a Rule, Start Actions and Stop Actions.
(A Rule is built from Operators/Expressions - The 'Logic Gate' like part)

I've been using Vis.js to do this. I simply pass some JSON to the front end and use a recursive method to build the network as shown on the diagram.

In most cases this works great and the nodes are positioned such that the diagram is readable. However, occasionally I get diagrams similar to that shown on the screenshot where the links between the Operators (AND/OR) and the Expressions (Orange rectangles) cross unnecessarily (Hopefully the 2nd screenshot shows this!).

Does anyone have any advice on what I can do to resolve this issue while sticking with the Hierarchical view? Is there a way to save and load the position of the nodes in the network? Can I implement a custom layout manager? Is it simply the way I'm parsing the JSON to build the diagram?

The options I'm using are below (I'm aware some of this is redundant but it's still a work in progress)

```
options = {
    physics: {
        enabled: false
    },
    manipulation: {
        enabled: false,
        initiallyActive: true,
        addEdge: function(edgeData,callback) {
            if (edgeData.from === edgeData.to) {
                var r = confirm("Do you want to connect the node to itself?");
                if (r === true) {
                    callback(edgeData);
                }
            }
            else {
                callback(edgeData);
            }
        },
        addNode: function(nodeData,callback) {
            callback(nodeData);
        }
    },
    layout: {
        randomSeed: 270238,
        improvedLayout: false,
        hierarchical: {
            enabled:true,
            levelSeparation: 150,
            nodeSpacing: 100,
            treeSpacing: 20,
            blockShifting: true,
            edgeMinimization: false,
            parentCentralization: true,
            direction: 'LR',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
            sortMethod: 'directed'   // hubsize, directed
        }
    },
    interaction: {
        dragNodes :true,
        tooltipDelay: 3600000      // Set a really big delay - one hour
    },
    edges: {
        smooth: {
            type: 'continuous',
            forceDirection: 'none'
        },
    },
    nodes: {
        fixed: {
            x:false,
            y:false
        },
        widthConstraint: {
            minimum: 50,
            maximum: 100
        }
    },
    locale: 'mm',
    locales: locales,
},
```

[image: VIS 1]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46927541/3995261 and linked questions

Comment: Will have a look, thanks